# Not able to connect the DB from Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, xampp

I have started jsp servlet application with Xampp Server,
In which I have `dbconnection.java` and `LoginValidator.java` (servlet) files.

I'm getting an error while trying to access the database from servlet (`LoginValidator.java`).

It is getting the following error:

```
Class Not found Exception : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I have imported the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar`. I have searched a lot but could not find the solution.

Comment: make sure it is in the right location see your answers

Answer (score 1):

Where the mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar is in your project? And is mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar in classpath project?

See in you application on server if mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` file inside the folder:

```
YOUR_WEBAPPS_FOLDER/YOUR_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/lib/
```

so that it will be available in the classpath when your servlet is compiled by the web container.

Answer (score 0):

try to put your connector jar into /WEB-INF/lib/ directory of your application.
If it doesn't work then try this ugly trick: put your mysql-connector jar into \xampp\tomcat\lib\ directory. You may have incorrectly imported connector jar so it is not on the classpath.